# Best way to get the JSON object from a string

Tags: java

I've a string which contains a JSON object. How can I find if it has a JSON object and fetch it? Is there any better way instead of splitting by characters?

```
"String Notify : {"id": "1234", "transactionId": "TR-001", "timestamp": "1575445871"} with result success"
```

Comment: If it is a single JSON object and there can be no other curly braces around, you can experiment with getting the `substring()` between `indexOf('{')` and `lastIndexOf('}')+1`.

Comment: You can check the JSON occurrence in the String using a regex, then substring the value and convert the result in JSON Object.

Comment: @tevemadar, can you post as an answer with the example, so that I can accept it

Comment: @user2342558, pls provide with the answer, so that I can accept and upvote

Comment: Pretty sure that what @tevemadar suggested not going for work with `aaa { aaa {"id": 123} aaa` and other inputs that have unbalanced or nested brackets. Same with regex, I don't think you can use it for more complex cases

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I would guess it is some part of a logfile, and the focus is not on handling all possible character sequences properly, but really just getting a known JSON part from a line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple version with `last/IndexOf()`:

```
String testData="String Notify : {\"id\": \"1234\", \"transactionId\": \"TR-001\", \"timestamp\": \"1575445871\"} with result success";
int jsonStart=testData.indexOf('{');
int jsonEnd=testData.lastIndexOf('}')+1;
if(jsonStart>=0 && jsonEnd>jsonStart) {
    String jsonPart=testData.substring(jsonStart,jsonEnd);
    System.out.println(jsonPart);
}
```

Test: https://ideone.com/rgiH10

But this code just gets the part what looks like a stringified JSON object, from the bigger string, parsing is another story.

Comment: Thank you. Parsing job leave it to me :) I'll handle that

Answer (score 2):

A solution that will handle nested and unbalanced objects and return the substring corresponding to the first outermost JSON object :

```
int depth=0;
StringBuilder currentJsonString=new StringBuilder();
boolean containsValidJson = false;
for (char c: input.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '{') { depth++; }
    else if (c == '}' && depth > 0) { // if depth==0, the } isn't part of a JSON object
        depth--;
        if (depth == 0) {
            currentJsonString.append(c);
            containsValidJson = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (depth > 0) { currentJsonString.append(c); }
}
// at this point if containsValidJson is true, call currentJsonString.toString() to get the JSON object
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/4SWwEI).

Note that it doesn't validate other features of JSON, only correct brackets. You will want to pass the extracted substring to a proper JSON parser if you want to validate it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can do it using many methods:

**Method 1: GSON**
The Gson from Google is an open-source library to deal with JSON in Java programs

```
Gson g = new Gson();
Player p = g.fromJson(jsonString, Player.class)
```

**Method 2: Jackson**
Jackson is the most popular JSON parsing library in Java world. It's fast and feature-rich.

```
Player ronaldo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Player.class);
```

Obviously for them you need to know the format of JSON String and create a class with those attributes (Like Player.class). If the format of JSON is unknown, you'll have to split manually in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not a very good solution but it will work. You can improve the regex to auto include the curly brace instead of concatenating them.

```
        String x="String Notify : {\"id\": \"1234\", \"transactionId\": \"TR-001\", \"timestamp\": \"1575445871\"} with result success";
        Pattern logEntry = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\{)([^\\}]+)(?=\\})");
        Matcher matchPattern = logEntry.matcher(x);

        while(matchPattern.find()) {
            String json = "{" + matchPattern.group(1) + "}";
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                System.out.println("Found a json");
           }catch (JSONException err){
                err.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
```

Don't forget to add [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20180813) to your library